# opera 9 and click event

Tags: javascript

I have a simple code:

```
<div id="test" onclick="test()"></div>

<script>
    document.getElementById("test").click()
</script>
```

Why this code don't work in Opera < 9.5 ?

Answer (score 0):

Where are you declaring your `test()` function?

Another note, I'd recommend using `addEventListener` instead of the element's `onclick` attribute:

```
var test = document.getElementById('test');
test.addEventListener('click', test, false);
function test() {}
```

Comment: Also, I should mention that `click()` is not a JavaScript method.